# Adding parts of one file to another file

Tags: command-line, files, text-processing

I am new to Linux, doing some opencv stuff.

I have a file, `positives.txt` with 1400 pictures names and coordinates like this:

```
./positives/1.jpg 1 9 25 70 21
./positives/2.jpg 1 13 5 45 38
./positives/3.jpg 1 8 20 63 14
./positives/4.jpg 2 4 25 76 23 11 17 67 21
```

...etc

and another file `samples.txt` like this:

```
./positives/800.jpg 
./positives/801.jpg 
./positives/802.jpg 
./positives/803.jpg
```

...etc

I want to make a bash script that will copy all the numbers from file `positives.txt` to file `samples.txt`. So the output will be like this

```
./positives/800.jpg 1 9 25 70 21
./positives/801.jpg 1 13 5 45 38
./positives/802.jpg 1 8 20 63 14
./positives/803.jpg 2 4 25 76 23 11 17 67 21
```

...etc

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your sample

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f2- positives.txt | paste -d '' samples.txt -
./positives/800.jpg 1 9 25 70 21
./positives/801.jpg 1 13 5 45 38
./positives/802.jpg 1 8 20 63 14
./positives/803.jpg 2 4 25 76 23 11 17 67 21
```

This assumes that the files are already sorted and that the first line of `positives` has the numbers you want to add to the first line of `samples`

#### Notes

- `cut -d ' ' -f2-` cut from `positives` all the fields from the second field onwards, assuming it to be space delimited
- `|` pass the `cut` output as stdin to `paste`
- `paste -d '' samples.txt -` paste lines from stdin onto lines from `samples` without adding any delimiting characters (the file as entered here has a space at the end of each line. If that is not the reality, use `paste -d ' '` to get a space)

Comment: Love u babyyyyyy! I only added:     $ cut -d ' ' -f2- positives.txt | paste -d '' samples.txt -   >solution.txt       because without >solution.txt it only writes to terminal not to file (with  >solution.txt  it writes all to the new made solution.txt file)..   thanks one more time for saving me :*

Comment: @UnknownX any time, glad you solved it :D